# Is drools 5.5.0 compatible with Jdk 17

Tags: drools, java-17

I am using knowledge-api 5.5.0.Final and drools-compiler 5.5.0.Final. I am planning to upgrade from openjdk 1.8 to openjdk 17.

Is the above drools and knowledge api jars compatible with jdk17.

If not, what needs to be done? Does drool upgrade is required?.

I don't want to upgrade the drools hence, if drools is not compatible, any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Drools 5.5 is 10+ years old so it's hard to find someone with a direct experience of this upgrade.
My suggestion is: try to execute with Java 17 your application compiled with Java 8.

My applications using Drools 7.73.0.Final and compiled with Java 8 work fine with Java 17 if you run the JVM with:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Depending on other characteristics of your app, you could have to add some dependency in your POM (before recompiling with Java 8).  For example, since my apps are web services, I added the following dependency that was present in Java 8 but not in Java 17:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>  <!-- For Java 17 -->
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now my apps work both with Java 8 and Java 17 (useful because some customer is slow in migrating to Java 17).  Of course I consider it just as the first step of a full migration.  In your case the full migration should include an upgrade of Drools, IMHO.

Comment: In addition to this, the trick is going to be that the DRL cannot be updated to use any Java functionality introduced in any version of Java >= 8. The actual Java code in the app, sure, can use all the modern syntaxes; but the DRL itself cannot. I built and ran a Drools 5.1-based application with JDK 17 about a year back, and as long as the Drools DRLs kept their syntaxes at Java 7 level or earlier, it was fine.

Comment: I am getting 
Got Exception [java.lang.RuntimeException: Rules compilation failed or interrupted]
While running Drools 7.73.0.Final and compiled with Java 8 code using Java 17